# Windows 10 upgrade after formatting

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a laptop with Windows 7 : Home edition, 64 bits. SP1.

The windows update were done and I upgraded to Windows 10. No problem. But I wanted to reformat my computer and though it was a possibility during the installation. It was not.

So I formatted my computer with my old version (Win 7 SP1, home edition, 64bits) with a ISO image. I reinstalled the OS, put the license key, made the Windows update ... But the "Get windows 10" icon is not displayed anymore.

I searched and found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/i-want-to-reserve-my-free-copy-of-windows-10-but-i/848b5cce-958b-49ae-a132-a999a883265b) article.

They said that 2 updates MUST be present. I got them as you can see below

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism /online /get-packages | findstr 3035583
Identité du package : Package_for_KB3035583~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.29

C:\Windows\system32>dism /online /get-packages | findstr 2952664
Identité du package : Package_for_KB2952664~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.13.2
```

I tried to run the script but it failed in an infinite loop ...

I also tried to delete the content of `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and run this `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` and re-run the windows update. But it say that I already have all the current update.

I have reboot my computer and waited for a long time before posting this.

Comment: You are unlikely going to get the icon because A) you performed the upgrade already 2) they are doing a phased roll out and once you upgraded you your new installation would be in a different phase C) because the sky is appears to be blue in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wait for the icon to show up in order to do an upgrade.  You can do the upgrade manually by downloading the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

However, you shouldn't need to upgrade at all.  If you successfully upgraded to Windows 10 from your old Windows 7 install, you should be able to do a clean install because Microsoft now recognizes your computer as one that is allowed to have Windows 10.  You can use the same tool linked above to make a DVD of the Windows 10 installer or put the installer on a USB flash drive.  When you boot from that DVD/USB, it will give you the option to do a clean install.

Comment: Technically you can also just do a Reset and you will achieve exactly what happens when you do a clean install.

Comment: @Ramhound
I created a bootable USB with the Windows tool. Windows 10 is working fine but my product key (who was recognize in Windows 7) is no longer available. They said that the key does not work ... Any idea ?

Comment: @Raccoon you cannot use the Windows 7 key in the Windows 10 installer. If you have previously installed Windows 10 **using the upgrade tool**, then you can install Windows 10 from the USB drive and click "skip" when it asks for the product key.  If you have not done the upgrade, you need to go back to Windows 7 and do the upgrade from there.

Comment: @MosheKatz
I used the USB option because the upgrade option was not working. I was not able to upgrade. Neither by Windows Update nor by Windows tool with the "Upgrade" option... Am I stuck somewhere in a Windows non-managed situation ?

Comment: It isn't SUPPOSE to work.  If you want a windows 10 installation that can be activated you will need to perform an upgrade and NOT do a clean install the first time.  Your answer indicates you did do an upgrade the first time, if that is the case, your clean install will eventually activate once the actiavtation server responds